# Unwanted movement of content in eps files when compiled with PDFLaTeX (PDFLaTeX, chemnum, auto-pst-pdf)

Tags: pdftex, eps, includegraphics, auto-pst-pdf, chemnum

To include chemical structures in my pdf file, I export the content (from ChemDraw) as .eps file and include it via includegraphics. Additionally, I number my compounds using the chemnum package via TMP tags in the .eps file.

Recently, I had to install MikTeX and Texmaker from scratch and from then on, this standard procedure did not work properly anymore. I still get the desired output and chemnum works fine, but some content is slightly shifted. While comparing the .eps and the final .pdf file content, it is cleary visible that, for instance, horizontal spacing in the H11C5-groups is messed up and that the atom numbers above 10 are strangely blurred.

[image: Comparison between .eps (top) and .pdf (bottom) file.]

The MWE is compiled using PDFLaTeX (pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape %.tex).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{chemnum}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
\replacecmpd{ald1}
\replacecmpd{ald2}
\replacecmpd{aldol}
    \includegraphics{Test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I also checked different versions of ChemDraw to ensure that ChemDraw should not be the problem.

The .eps file can be downloaded at: https://we.tl/t-e44KBsGnfH

What can I do about the problem?

Comment: looks like a font problem, but without the eps it is not possible to debug it.

Comment: I added a link to the .eps file in the question.

Comment: works okay for me. Do you have a full miktex installation?

Comment: What do you mean with 'full'? 
I downloaded the 'basic-miktex-2.9.7342-x64.exe' from https://miktex.org/download on 11.02.2020 and installed Texmaker (Texmaker_5.0.4_Win_x64.msi) afterwards.

Comment: Then you don't have the full miktex. It could be that something is missing there (but I can't know, I only saw a post suggesting this).

Comment: I installed the full MikTex and now it works, indeed. Thank you very much @UlrikeFischer. Could you please write an answer so that I can accept it?
In case someone is wondering about the full MikTex: Go to https://miktex.org/download, click on 'All downloads' and download 'Net installer'